# I am trying to create a chatbot and I am at a part in which an error is showing: 'similarity_scores_list' is not defined. Let me show u some code

Tags: python, chatbot

```
    #Creating bot response
def bot_response(user_input):
  user_input = user_input.lower()
  sentence_list.append(user_input)
  bot_response = ''
  cm = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(sentence_list)
  similarity_scores = cosine_similarity(cm[-1], cm)
  similarity_scores_list = similarity_scores.flatten()
  index = index_sort(similarity_scores_list)



  user_input = ' Hello world '
  sentence_list.append(user_input)
  bot_response = ''
  cm = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(sentence_list)
  similarity_scores = cosine_similarity(cm[-1], cm)
  similarity_scores_list = similarity_scores.flatten()
  index = index_sort(similarity_scores_list)






similarity_scores_list
```

Now the error is:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3a37cf5851ae> in <module>()
----> 1 similarity_scores_list

NameError: name 'similarity_scores_list' is not defined
```

This error comes when I run:  similarity_scores_list

I am using google colaboratory.

Please help me as i am a beginner. I am following a youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KZwRBg4-P0&t=1066s

Comment: Because you're trying to run this in the REPL and the name is defined in a function that you haven't even run. This YouTube video is not helping you at all because I think you've gone well out of your depth here

Comment: `similarity_scores_list` is a local variable that's defined within the scope of the function. Outside, it means nothing. That's the issue.

Comment: I would suggest taking a step back and learning about "scope" and "names". [This](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer** - you did not run these code:

```
user_input = ' Hello world '
sentence_list.append(user_input)
bot_response = ''
cm = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(sentence_list)
similarity_scores = cosine_similarity(cm[-1], cm)
similarity_scores_list = similarity_scores.flatten()
index = index_sort(similarity_scores_list)
```

Just copy those code to a new cell and click the start button like the video. Then you run

```
similarity_scores_list
```

**Long Answer** -
What he did in the video is basically copying the code in the function outside and replace the function input with a manual input ("Hello World"). Maybe you run the function code but that just means you defined the function. Defining the function will not run the code. So you have to copy the code outside and ran again.